# Cannot clear Input Stream by cin.ignore() and cin.clear()

Tags: c++

I cannot clear Input Stream although I have used cin.ignore(), cin.clear(), but all they is NOT working in my program. How to fix it? Help me pls, Thanks you

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
using namespace std;
void Input_data(char name_of_student[], float &Score_of_Math, float &Score_of_Literature)
{


cout<<"Enter Name of Student: ";
cin.getline(name_of_student,1);
cin.ignore();
cout<<"Enter Score_of_Math: ";
cin >> Score_of_Math;
cout << "Enter Score_of_Literature: ";
cin >> Score_of_Literature;
cout << name_of_student;
}

int main()
{


char name_of_student[20];
float Score_of_Math;
float Score_of_Literature;
Input_data(name_of_student, Score_of_Math, Score_of_Literature);

}
```

Comment: `cin.getline(name_of_student,1);` looks odd. Do you really want to read only 1 char? Also  `cin.ignore` will ignore 1 char by default. Maybe you should take a look at the reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore & https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline. If something doesn't work as expected often your expectations are wrong.

Comment: Secondly: `char name_of_student[20];` will not initialize the values in the array. They contain garbage data and when you print them with `cout << name_of_student;` you probably go out of bounds. Anyway if those hints don't help you, please add input and expected and actual output to clarify your problem :)

Comment: Thanks you. cin.getline will get '\n', afterward it stopping.Hence '\n' is not in "cin".So I don't need to clear Input Stream, I only need replace cin.getline(name_of_student,1) by cin.getline(name_of_student,9 or other number). Right?

Answer (score 0):

`cin::getline`'s second parameter says how many characters the char array will accept at most. The function will automatically append a terminating `\0` in there, so you left no room to load any useful data. The function extracts nothing from the input and in that case it sets failbit on the stream to true. You'd have to match the number to the size of the array and report an error in case it is too small.

But what you really should do is to store the name in `std::string`. That will solve this issue and leave less space for other bugs.